# Why does Copy button copy 'undefined' instead of copying value from html dom?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to make my own user script for https://mlwbd.ltd/movie/don-2022

I wish to copy the value of specified hidden input

```
preTag = document.getElementsByName("FU");
p = preTag[0];
console.log(p);

Ekra = document.getElementsByClassName("linktabs");
q = Ekra[0];
console.log(q);

function copy(ele) {
    let temp = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.value = ele.textContent;
    temp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    temp.remove();
}

btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "copy"
btn.onclick = function(){
    copy("p");
};

q.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), q.childNodes[0])
q.insertBefore(btn, q.childNodes[0])
```

The Html code is

```
input type="hidden" name="FU" value="https://songslyric.site/links/46905/"
```

I want to copy the  Value of  name="FU" when I click the button.
The code I pasted is created from google chrome snippets.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you copy-paste from your source code incorrectly, or does it actually say `copy("p`? Because that's not valid code.

Comment: actually that is  a mistake i typed copy("p"); on my code even so the button copy undefined & of course  I'm a beginner on JavaScript.

Comment: The `ele` parameter of the `copy` function is expected to be an element, but you are sending it a string (`"p"`). Edit: Btw, execCommand is deprecated.

Comment: I'm a beginner bro i created this script by following a video but i cant understand it. If if dont mind can you please fix that code for me? i followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4dSWJFIQ0A

Comment: Whatever video you watched was a bad tutorial that should be avoided. This is not good (or even modern) code. I suggest that you study the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Then help me with my code bro I will be thankful to you

Comment: Have you tried sending the actual element `p` to `copy` instead of sending the text string `"p"`? Because that's the first (and hopefully only) step towards fixing this issue. I will not write your code for you. I'm just here to point you in the right direction. The rest is your job.

Comment: I have also tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your other question:

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         adsgo.digital
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      0.1
    // @include        https://adsgo.digital/
    // @include        https://adsgo.digital/*
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    (function() {
        'use strict';
        const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

        $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', init_css() );

        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#mybutt').addEventListener('click', () => {
                //alert('hi');
                const fu = $('.posts-dynamic.posts-container form input[name=FU6]');
                //console.log(fu.value);
                copy2clip(fu);
            });
        },500);


    })();
    function init_css(){
        return `
        <button id="mybutt">Copy2Clip</button>
        <style id="myInitCss">
            #mybutt{position:absolute;top:90px;left:45%;height:30px;width:120px;}
            #mybutt{background:#0073ea;color:white;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;}
            #mybutt{z-index:99999;}
        </style>
        `;
    }
    function copy2clip(ele) {
        let temp = document.createElement('textarea');
        document.body.appendChild(temp);
        temp.value = ele.value;
        temp.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        temp.remove();
    }
```

#### Notes:

1. You can compare this answer to the previous one and you'll notice that only one line has changed.
2. The topic to study to understand how to reference the HTML scaffolding as I did is called: "CSS Selectors".  The JavaScript `querySelector()` directive uses CSS selectors to specifically target the desired HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         mlwbd.ltd
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://mlwbd.ltd/movie/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

    $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', init_css() );

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#mybutt').addEventListener('click', () => {
            //alert('hi');
            const fu = $('#download table form input[name=FU]');
            //console.log(fu.value);
            copy2clip(fu);
        });
    },500);


})();
function init_css(){
    return `
    <button id="mybutt">Copy2Clip</button>
    <style id="myInitCss">
        #mybutt{position:absolute;top:90px;left:45%;height:30px;width:120px;}
        #mybutt{background:#0073ea;color:white;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;}
        #mybutt{z-index:99999;}
    </style>
    `;
}
function copy2clip(ele) {
    let temp = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.value = ele.value;
    temp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    temp.remove();
}
```

#### Notes:

1. Despite the `$` character, this code is not jQuery (it is vanilla javascript)
2. You can uncomment the `alert()` and `console.log` to see how things are working at that point.

Comment: cssyphus bro thanks for you co operation. Your codes works well. I also have a favor to ask will you help me to execute another script for one other website . The website pattern is almost same but I can't figure out.

Comment: https://en.adsgo.digital/go.php?i=aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uYm9hYmQuY29tL2VtYmVkP3Bob3RvPUNYV3JmR2lGYkR4TjJNSXVrb0NGdVMzTjY=      This webpage has the same structure but it's input value is 'FU6'

Comment: '<input type="hidden" name="FU6" value="https://cdn.boabd.com/embed?photo=zsAWnUoIohC4pWheAYS1yYwkC">' please help me @cssyphus bro

Comment: I don't how to use stack overflow function very well so if I made mistake please forgive me. I'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: To select a correct answer, click the checkmark beside the answer - that gives points to the person who answered. Also, you may (if you wish) also reward an answer beyond that by clicking the ^ (up triangle) beside the answer. For any answer, you can do none of these, one or both. However, only one answer can be checkmarked as the best answer.